# Writing build.gradle in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle, eclipse-plugin

I want to write build.gradle in Eclipse and I need following support for that.

I need to write proper Groovy code to handle the complete build system and to deal with a certain file editing part. I want a support in eclipse which will show me all the methods available in dropdown for a particular class after typing classobject (methods dropdown). I want it to be the way it supports for Java programs.

I tried to add a couple of plugins in Eclipse, but they are not providing me this dropdown support. What plugin would work for this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have no experience with it because I do not use Eclipse, but the makers of Gradle have written their own plug-in for Eclipse. I suspect it makes working with Gradle in Eclipse easier: https://gradle.org/press-release/eclipse-gradle/